# how to make a tab active when loaded from different page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a  sub menus available in my page Manage Profile. By default first tab will be active , but when I wanted to come from different page to particular menu changepassword or Payment gateway. I couldnt make it active. Need assistance.

Current Page:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" >
    <li class="tablist" ng-class="tab === 1? 'active' : ''">
        <a ng-click="changeTab(1)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>MANAGE PROFILE</b></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="tab === 2? 'active' : ''" style="border-left: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">
        <a ng-click="changeTab(2)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>CHANGE PASSWORD</b></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="tab === 3? 'active' : ''">
        <a ng-click="changeTab(3)" style="cursor: pointer;"><b>PAYMENT HISTORY</b></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.tab = 1;

$scope.changeTab = function(idx)
{
    $scope.tab = idx;
};
```

app.js:

```
 .when('/manageProfile', {
                controller: 'ManageProfileController',
                templateUrl: 'view/manageProfile.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
```

Profile.html

```
<li><a href=#/manageProfile>ManageProfile</a></li>
<li><a href =#/manageProfile>ChangePassword</a></li>
```

How to onload make change password tab active when change password is selected in profile page.

Comment: You may wanna insert url params to check what is the current active tab

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle for this.

Comment: call the first tab with 1 by default like **$scope.changeTab(1);**

Comment: Hi , my page url is actually #/manageProfile which by default open first tab, how to make second tab open. thats the point.

Answer (score 0):

I made this on my project, you can check my routes and controllers

`garageCtrl.js`

```
class GarageController {
  /*@ngInject*/
 constructor($state,$stateParams) {
 this.$state = $state;
 this.$stateParams = $stateParams;

 this.filter = this.$stateParams.filter || 'all';

// set Initial tab based on the params in URL;
switch(this.filter) {
  case 'all': {
    this.activeTab = 0;
    break;
  }
  case 'commercial': {
    this.activeTab = 1;
    break;
  }
  case 'residential': {
    this.activeTab = 2;
    break;
  }
   default: null
  }
}

filterChanged(filter) {
 this.filter = filter;
 //SOME CODES FOR ASYNC//
 this.getGarageList(filter);
 this.pageChanged(this.page);
}

}

GarageController.$inject = [
  '$state',
  '$stateParams'
  ];
export default GarageController;
```

this is the view, I used directive for my tabs `angular-bootstrap`:

```
   <uib-tabset active="$ctrl.activeTab" justified="true">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="All"
      ng-click="$ctrl.filterChanged('all')">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Commercial"
      ng-click="$ctrl.filterChanged('commercial')">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Residential"
      ng-click="$ctrl.filterChanged('residential')">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Valet"
      ng-click="$ctrl.filterChanged('valet')">
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

and this is my `routes.js`, I used `angular-ui-router`:

```
.state('dashboard.garage', {
  url: '/dashboard/garage?page&filter',
  views: { 
    '': { template: '<garage></garage>' },
    'content@dashboard.garage': { 
      templateUrl: 'src/app/templates/admin.dashboard.garage.template.html' 
    }
  },
  params: {
    page: {
      value: '1',
      squash: true
    },
    filter: {
      value: 'all',
      squash: true
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $routeParams.

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

       .when('/manageProfile', {
            controller: 'ManageProfileController',
            templateUrl: 'view/manageProfile.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/manageProfile/:tab', {
            controller: 'ManageProfileController',
            templateUrl: 'view/manageProfile.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
       //:tab is the route parameter
    });


    app.controller("ManageProfileController",['$scope','$routeParams' ,function ($scope,$routeParams ) {
         $scope.tab = 1;
          if($routeParams.tab=="2" || $routeParams.tab=="3"){
            $scope.tab= Number($routeParams.tab) ; //getting the route parameter "tab"
         }
    }]);


<li><a href=#/manageProfile>ManageProfile</a></li>   //no Route param
<!-- or <li><a href=#/manageProfile/1>ManageProfile</a></li>--> // tab=1
<li><a href =#/manageProfile/2>ChangePassword</a></li> // tab=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/F2wgC/23/

```
ng-class="{'active' : tab == 1}"
```